# Python turtle throws error when inputting RGB values to bgcolor()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

My code throws an error, which, summarized, reads:

"The built-in function for color in Turtle can't do the inequality used in determining color values using both a built-in function of Python and an integer"

```
from turtle import *

pen = Turtle()
screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)
screen.bgcolor('white')

def pen_color(i):
    print("Input a number between 1 and 255 for red")
    red = input
    print("Input a number between 1 and 255 for green")
    green = input
    print("Input a number between 1 and 255 for blue")
    blue = input
    screen.bgcolor(red, green, blue)

pen_color(pen)
pen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: You need to include the parentheses to call the function: `input()`, not `input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:  As @PatrickHaugh notes:

```
print("Input a number between 1 and 255 for red")
red = input
```

isn't going to do what you want/expect.  Either do:

```
print("Input a number between 1 and 255 for red")
red = input()
```

Or better yet:

```
red = input("Input a number between 1 and 255 for red")
```

Next, this won't work as `exitonclick()` is a method of `Screen` not `Turtle`:

```
pen.exitonclick()
```

Finally, the reason you're running into problems with color, is that `bgcolor()` wants numeric argument and you passed it strings.  You need to do:

```
screen.bgcolor(int(red), int(green), int(blue))
```

Putting this all together:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def pen_color():
    red = input("Input a number between 1 and 255 for red: ")
    green = input("Input a number between 1 and 255 for green: ")
    blue = input("Input a number between 1 and 255 for blue: ")

    screen.bgcolor(int(red), int(green), int(blue))

screen = Screen()
screen.colormode(255)

pen_color()

pen = Turtle()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: `red = input` is perfectly valid python (it just doesn't do what they expect it to do).

Comment: Yes, you're right it was *runnable* as far as syntax goes.  The errors all would all happen at runtime.  I've adjusted my answer accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! The code is looking and running great in my editor.